# Can I restore data from copied backup set in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, backup

I have copy of backup set (level 0 and level 1 incremental backups) from Oracle 11g running on Linux.

Can I restore data from this set on other machine which running Windows without connection to source database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be no. There is no way to restore rman backupset from Linux to Windows directly.